# Can't Get HTML Element by TagName in VB

Tags: html, vb.net

I am trying to get elements by tag names in my VB code like I used to in VBA, but cannot figure out how. I open up a new browser window, yet from then on the code gets stuck.

```
Public ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Private Sub TEST(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Keyword As Long
    ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate("http://google.com/")
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    Dim Doc As HtmlDocument
    Doc = ie.Document
    Keyword = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("td")(8).InnerText
    MsgBox(Keyword)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding

```
Imports mshtml
```

At top of the code.